# Is there any good way to remove elements in the vector or deque? provide some sample code is more than welcome

Tags: c++, stl

For example, I good 2 vector, say vector  current, vector  to_delete. Is there some good way to delete elements which appear both in current.

Here is my way to do it. I guess it not looks good. So please help me out. Thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  vector <double> current;
  current.push_back(1.1);
  current.push_back(2.1); 
  current.push_back(3.1); 
  current.push_back(4.1); 
  current.push_back(5.1); 
  current.push_back(6.1); 
  current.push_back(7.1); 
  current.push_back(8.1);
  vector <double> to_delete;
  to_delete.push_back(2.1);
  to_delete.push_back(5.1);
  for(int i = 0;i<to_delete.size();i++){
    int loc = -1;
    for(int j = 0; j < current.size();j++)
    {
      if(current[j]==to_delete[i]){
        loc = j;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(loc >= 0){
      current.erase(current.begin()+loc);
    }
  }

  for(int i = 0;i < current.size();i++){
    cout << current[i]<< endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Didn't check on the validity of code, but approach looks clean to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`std::find()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/) instead of a manual loop to find the position of the element that should be deleted.

```
std::vector<double>::iterator del =
      std::find(current.begin(), current.end(), to_delete[i]);
if (del != current.end())
    current.erase(del);
```

Answer (score 5):

Probably the simplest way is to construct a new vector using `std::set_difference` (both vectors have to be sorted for this to work):

```
std::vector<double> diff;
std::set_difference(current.begin(), current.end(),
                    to_delete.begin(), to_delete.end(),
                    std::back_inserter(diff));
```

Comment: This presumes that the original vectors are sorted (which they appear to be in the example, but just sayin').

Comment: +1 Although you should note that both ranges *must* be sorted first.

Comment: +1, that's nicer than what I'd started to write using std::remove_if

Comment: thank you for the nice solution, Sorry, I forgot to mention both vector is not sorted.

Comment: @Monkey: You can sort the vectors using `std::sort(current.begin(), current.end());`.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with something like:

```
std::vector<double>::iterator iter
    = std::find_first_of( current.begin(), current.end(),
                          to_delete.begin(), to_delete.end() );
while ( iter != current.end() ) {
    iter = std::find_first_of( current.erase( iter ), current.end(),
                               to_delete.begin(), to_delete.end() );
}
```

Alternatively, you can define a predicate:

```
template <typename Container>
class IsElementOf
{
    Container const* m_container;
public:
    IsElementOf(Container const& container)
        : m_container(&container)
    {
    }

    bool operator()( typename Container::value_type const& v ) const
    {
        return std::find( m_container->begin(),
                          m_container->end(),
                          v )
                != m_container->end();
    }
};

template <typename Container>
inline IsElementOf<Container>
isElementOf( Container const& container )
{
    return IsElementOf<Container>(container);
}
```

and use std::remove_if:

```
current.erase(
    std::remove_if( current.begin(), current.end(),
                    isElementOf( to_delete ) ),
    current.end() );
```

(This is really only a valid proposal if you have to do this sort of
thing in a number of different places.  Or if you can use boost::bind to
generate the IsElementOf in place, but that's difficult, because the
compiler won't know where to start when it comes to figuring out the
type, so you'll have to explicitly specify it somewhere.)

Comment: You could use `Container::const_reference` instead of `Container::value_type const &` - it is intended for just this.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y Good point.  I'll admit that I'm used to value_type and the iterators, and pretty much ignore the other typedef's in the containers.

Answer (score 0):

First you should note that in your specific example that `x.1` is NOT fully representable in a base two floating point format and that attempting to compare those values may result in inequality due to the code the compiler generates even if it appears that it should work.

Next, is `vector` really the right kind of container if you need arbitrary deletion like that? Did you consider using `set` or `multiset` instead?

If you need a random-access container then you can use the `set_difference` method suggested by @Space_C0wb0y or use `std::remove`:

```
for(int i = 0;i<to_delete.size();i++)
{
    current.erase(std::remove(current.begin(), current.end(), to_delete[i]), current.end());
}
```

Assuming `n = current.size()` and `m = to_delete.size()`, If it's already sorted, `set_difference` should be linear. If it is not sorted, it would be `O(n log n) + O(m log m)`. The remove approach would be `O(m n)`

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I forgot to mention it is not sorted. I will make the question clear next time. :->